# jQuery fadeout a div that's revealed by php and not Javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

Seems like this might be easy, but from reading other SO answers there are a number of ways for it to possibly work:

I have the "thanks" div below that shows when a php form is sucessfully submitted:

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
<div class="thanks"></div>
```

The page does not reload after the form is submitted; the php for the form is included in the page header, the php above is in `<body>`, and when the form is submitted, the "thanks" div appears.

Question: How can the div be faded out (or simply removed) after a few seconds?

Document ready doesn't seem like it would work because the page is not reloaded. Can jQuery detect the appearance of the div and then start the fadeout timer?

If possible, I'd like to stay with the php form and not move to a jQuery form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're submitting the form and it's not via ajax, then your page is reloading, in which case you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".thanks").delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

This would wait 5 seconds then fade out the element, about as simple as it gets :)  If it doesn't find the div with `$(".thanks")` then no problem, it just won't have anything to animate...meaning you can stick this in an external script without any issues.

Comment: Is `delay()` just a wrapper for `setTimeout()`... hmm is jQuery going to wrap every piece of native JavaScript? :P I suppose it looks more *jQuery* doing it this way (and is easier).

Comment: @alex - Not really, though it's similar, this adds a delay to a specific queue, when no name is passed it's the animation queue.  For example: `.fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut()...`  You could also use it as a delay inside any other queue if you wanted: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: So does that function go in a $(document).ready block in the header? I tried it with no luck. And is there other markup that goes in the body?

Comment: @songdogtech - This code can go in any script block after jQuery is included in the page, the `$(function() { })` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { })`.  What's currently happening? and do you have a page I can get to by chance? that'd make finding the issue very fast.

Comment: Thanks, I'm puzzled; can't see what I need to see via Firebug.  http://davidjamesduncan.com

Comment: @songdogtech - You form submit via ajax, so in your `contact.js`, after this line in your post callback: `$(this).before('<p class="thanks">&....` put the `$(".thanks").delay(5000).fadeOut();` on the next line, let me know if it gives any more trouble :)

Comment: Arrrgggg.... I was concentrating so much on index that I forgot about contact.js. You're right; it's already ajax. And your delay works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the page is already loaded, you can print the fade out script in your ajax response:

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
<div class="thanks"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".thanks").delay(5000).fadeOut();
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the div to display:none? Then make it visible in the form submit code.